# Cycle through banner ads using Javascript, setInterval

Tags: javascript

Im really struggling in JS right now. I spent a few hours today changing code in and out and I can not get this to work:
I know an array or a loop might be better, but I can't even get the basic code to work right now.  Thanks :)

"use five images; Create a script that cycles through the images, displaying each image for five seconds using setInterval."

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http-//www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="">

<head>
    <title>Concerts</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    var curImage = "concert5";

    function bannerAd() {
        if (curImage == "concert1") {
            document.images[0].src= "images/concert2.gif";
            curImage = "concert2.gif";
        {

        if (curImage == "concert2") {
            document.images[0].src= "images/concert3.gif";
            curImage = "concert3";
        }

        if (curImage == "concert3") {
            document.images[0].src= "images/concert4.gif";
            curImage = "concert4";
        }

        if (curImage == "concert4") {
            document.images[0].src= "images/concert5.gif";
            curImage = "concert5";
        }

        if (curImage == "concert5") {
            document.images[0].src= "images/concert1.gif";
            curImage = "concert1";
        }
    }
/* ]]> */
</script>
</head>
<body onload= "curImage = setInterval('bannerAd()',5000);">
    <img src = ??? width="462" height="87" alt="Concert ads"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `curImage = "concert2.gif";` is your problem. Need I say more?

Comment: Rotate image means to make an image turn around some central point, by some angle.  Cycle through banner ads is what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks James I corrected my title.

Yes it is hw Oliver, but churning code wasn't doing me any good so I decided to reach out for some explanation.

Comment: @Shmiddty Thank You.  It is funny how obvious that is now that you pointed it out.  My attention to detail is coming along, but has a ways to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can clean up your code considerably:

```
var images = ['images/concert1.gif', 'images/concert2.gif', 'images/concert3.gif', 'images/concert4.gif', 'images/concert5.gif'];
var current = 3;

function rotate() {
    document.getElementById('image').src = images[current];
    current = (current + 1) % images.length;

}

window.onload = function() {
    rotate();
    setInterval(rotate, 5000);
}
```

Also, change your HTML. It's easier to target elements when they have an `id`:

```
<img id="image" width="462" height="87" alt="Concert ads" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.images[1]` would be the second `<img>` tag on the document, but you only have one. I believe you were looking for `document.images[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a number of problems.

- You typed `curImage = "concert2.git";` and then test against simply `"concert2"`
- Arrays in JavaScript start at 0, you used `document.images[0]`
- `setInterval` returns a number that you can use with `clearInterval`
- More a matter of preference, but the CDATA hack is ancient and doesn't need to be used anymore.

Here's what I suggest:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http-//www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="">

<head>
    <title>Concerts</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
    <img id="theImage" width="462" height="87" alt="Concert ads"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var curImage = 5, theImage = document.getElementById('theImage');

    function bannerAd() {
        theImage.src = 'images/concert' + curImage + '.gif';
        curImage = curImage % 5 + 1;
    }
    bannerAd(); // Set theImage to the initial image, in this case, concert5.gif
    setInterval(bannerAd, 5000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice how I moved the `<script>` tag to the bottom of the body: this is so that the DOM document is already loaded by the time our script executes.

Also notice how instead of manually checking for concert1, concert2, etc, then setting the next one, I store a number instead of a string and use the modulo operator (%). This operator returns the remainder of its operands (so 10 % 3 would evaluate to 1). You can use this to "wrap" a number around at a certain point. I use it so that `curImage` progresses 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and so on.

Comment: `curImage = curImage % 5 + 1;` will always skip the first image. You want `(curImage + 1) % 5`. Also, I'd get rid of that `onload` attribute on the `<body>` element.

Comment: Actually, no. I intentionally want `curImage % 5 + 1`. Play with it in a JavaScript console. `(curImage + 1) % 5` will go 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 whereas `curImage % 5 + 1` will go 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1. I tested it. Remember, the console is your friend. Oh yeah, thanks, I forgot to get rid of that.

Comment: My bad, I forgot you aren't using an array of images.

Comment: Yeah, an array might have been a better solution. This is a tad bit shorter though.

Answer (score 0):

I am struguling with the same as I am new to jss and is confusing as a maze. this is what I got form what you guys recomended. It passes the W3C validation but it doesn't show any imgs on my page.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
    <title>Concert Series</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var images = ['images/concert1.gif', 'images/concert2.gif', 'images/concert3.gif', 'images/concert4.gif', 'images/concert5.gif'];
var current = 3;

function rotate() {
    document.getElementById('image').src = images[current];
    current = (current + 1) % images.length;

}

window.onload = function() {
    rotate();
    setInterval(rotate, 5000);
}
/* ]]> */
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Consert Series</h1>
<img src=concert1.gif/concert2.gif/concert3.gif/concert4.gif/concert5.gif id="image" width="462" height="87" alt="Concert ads" />
</body>
</html>
```